# What is the difference between TransformStamped and PoseStamped

Tags: ros, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
what is the difference between geometry_msgs/TransformStamped and geometry_msgs/PoseStamped?
I know that the first one is used for transformation but is it possible to replace the second one with the first one?
I got the geometry_msgs/TransformStamped from [vicon_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/vicon_bridge) node but actually i need the PoseStamped to represent the pose of the robot and objects.
Maybe i miss understand something, any one can help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200221/what-is-the-difference-between-transformstamped-and-posestamped/) by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only real difference between them is that [TransformStamped](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TransformStamped.html) has a `child_frame_id` field, and [PoseStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) doesn't. This implies that the former specifies a transform from the header's `frame_id` to `child_frame_id`. However, it's just a message, and does not affect the `tf` transform tree.

In any case, just from a brief glance at the package wiki page, it looks like they're just stuffing a pose in there. You can pull the source code from their repo and modify it to output the message type you want.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-12-30**:
Thanks Tom,
I wrote a node that subscribes to TransformStamped and publish  PoseStamped.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
That will also work, though it adds an extra step.